# Why ServerSocket Object's accept method returns a Socket object with a different port

Tags: java, sockets, networking, port

I've searched stackoverflow for an answer to my question, but I can't get my answer from those threads. My question is why a ServeerSocket Object's `accept()` method returns a Socket object listening on a different port on the server machine, while the port that the server is listening to is another.

**JAVA** Code:

```
package chat.server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerApp {
    public String[] advices = {"Take smaller bites",
            "Go for the tight jeans. No they do NOT make you look fat.",
            "One word: inappropriate",
            "Just for today, be honest. Tell your boss what you *really* think",
            "You might want to rethink that haircut."};
    public ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ServerApp()
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4245);
            System.out.println("Server Started.");
        }catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerApp server = new ServerApp();
        while(true)
        {
                server.sendMessage();
        }

    }

    public void sendMessage()
    {
        String advice;
        try
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();//here comes my question
            System.out.println(socket.getPort());
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            advice = getAdvice();
            printWriter.write(advice);

            printWriter.close();
            System.out.println(advice);
        }catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getAdvice() {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * advices.length);
        return advices[random];
    }
}
```

Isn't that normal that the server listens and answers the client from the same port number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to get back the value 4245 (the port your server socket is listening on) from the connected socket, you want `getLocalPort`, not `getPort`.

[`getPort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getPort%28%29):

> Returns the **remote** port number to which this socket is connected.

[`getLocalPort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getLocalPort%28%29):

> Returns the **local** port number to which this socket is bound.

*(My emphasis)*

Comment: @Crowder, so you mean the client machine port by saying remote port which this socket is connected, right?

Comment: @1linecode: Right. A socket is connected to a port on both ends. (You probably knew that.) The client machine's port is "remote" from your server's perspective, and so the local port for your client socket will be the one on the server, where your server socket was listening. `getPort` gives you the *remote* port, on the client machine, which is unlikely to be the same (and will vary from connection to connection, even from the same machine).

Answer (score 0):

> why a ServeerSocket Object's accept() method returns a Socket object listening on a different port on the server machine

It doesn't. What you're looking at is the remote port, at the client end. The local port is given by `getLocalPort(),` and it is the same as the `ServerSocket's.`

NB Only the `ServerSocket` is 'listening'. The accepted `Socket` is *connected,* and ready for I/O.